# How to have root permission in the Grafana Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

I have a Grafana Docker container, when I make an interactive shell on this, this user is not a superuser, so I can't do something that needs the `sudo` permission:

```
docker exec -it grafana_service bash
```

In this container:

```
$ su
password:
```

I haven't any password!

Or I can't use from `chmod 777` to make full permission on a filesystem and etc.

---

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  grafana_sevice:
      image: grafana/grafana:5.1.3
      container_name: grafana_service
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "3010:3000"
      links:
        - another_service
```

Comment: if you want to open an interactive shell as root use -u 0 docker run option

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks, it works: `docker exec -it -u 0 grafana_service bash` then I had the root permission.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$ docker exec -it -u 0 grafana_service bash
# chmod 777 /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db
```

---

<sub>(Thanks to [@c4f4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597174/c4f4t0r))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

By default the Grafana container will run with uid/gid 472, so you can `chown -R 472:472 /your/grafana/dir` on the host, then the container will be able to write to it.

Comment: Where is `/your/grafana/dir` on the host? Is this case Grafana is a Docker container not installed on the host.